# Download photos with WebClient and increase download speed

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

I am using .Net 3.5 due to my limitations.
In a part of the project, I need to receive a list of values, many of which are photos.
Download the photo with the following code and put it in the image source that is supposed to show the photo.

sample url :[link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/Breathe-face-smile.svg/1200px-Breathe-face-smile.svg.png)

```
public static BitmapImage GetBitmapImage(string url)
    {
        Stream myStream;
        int BytesToRead = 100;
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

        try
        {
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.Headers.Set("Method", "method.ToString()");
                webClient.Headers.Set("Timeout", "Timeout");
                webClient.Headers.Set("KeepAlive", "true");
                webClient.Headers.Set("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
                IWebProxy proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
                proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                webClient.Proxy = proxy;
                myStream = webClient.OpenRead(url);
            }
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(myStream);
            byte[] bytebuffer = new byte[BytesToRead];
            int bytesRead = reader.Read(bytebuffer, 0, BytesToRead);

            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                memoryStream.Write(bytebuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = reader.Read(bytebuffer, 0, BytesToRead);
            }
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            bitmapImage.StreamSource = memoryStream;
            bitmapImage.EndInit();

            return bitmapImage;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return bitmapImage;
        }


    }
```

But when I use this code, since the size of the photos is not high, it is about 300kb, it takes a long time for all the photos to be downloaded and displayed.
My question is what to do with the code to speed it up.

Comment: First, don't use `WebClient` its life is about to end. Second use `HtppClient`, and the async and await pattern, Third, start the async method concurrently

Comment: I am using .Net 3.5 !!!!

Comment: And what about compression? You can use gzip for example...